# webpack splitChunks: how do I merge dependencies into a named chunk?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Suppose you have a project below:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-test-repo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "define-properties": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
// dynamically load the 'define-properties' module.
import('define-properties');
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            minSize: 0, // <- just to demonstrate the situation with small packages
            cacheGroups: {
                defineProperties: {
                    test: /node_modules\/define-properties\//,
                    name: 'define-properties',
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Note that the imported module **define-properties** has a single dependency **object-keys**.

I configured `splitChunks` in webpack.config.js so that contents of  `define-properties` are split into `define-properties.js`.

The result of running webpack is as follows:

```
$ npx webpack
Hash: 7d9500fb0e6bfd1e32d1
Version: webpack 4.20.2
Time: 127ms
Built at: 2018-10-08 03:25:47
               Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
             main.js   2.05 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
define-properties.js  754 bytes       1  [emitted]  define-properties
                2.js   2.08 KiB       2  [emitted]  
Entrypoint main = main.js
[0] ./index.js 81 bytes {0} [built]
    + 3 hidden modules
```

Here we get three output files: `main.js` for the content of `index.js`, `define-properties.js` for the `define-properties` module, and `2.js` for the `object-keys` module.

**Question**:

I want the chunk for `object-keys` to be merged into `define-properties` because it is only used by `define-properties`.

In other words, I want to pack `define-properties` and its dependencies into one named chunk by only specifying the parent module.

Although `test: /node_modules\/(?:define-properties|object-keys)\//` works for this example, I don't want to list all (potentially many) dependencies of `define-properties`.

How do I configure webpack to achieve it?